# Serializable isolation level in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, acid

Is there any way to achieve "SERIALIZABLE" isolation level in MongoDB , So what I want is that , the data/row/document that has been read within the transaction , shouldn't be allowed to be **read** or **modified** outside that transaction .

I know there is the way that could achieve results similar to SELECT....FOR UPDATE , using findOneAndModify() , but is there a way to rather do this using Isolation Level , maybe by modifying some read or write concern ?

I have been trying to figure this out for a long time now , any help is welcome .